seleniumbase (uc_driver) in Linux not found when using pyinstaller
I use seleniumbase in python script (Linux). When I run script python3 test.py in my virtual environment called .venv the script runs without warnings. Then I compile the script like this:
pyinstaller --specpath /home/metka/bot/prog_test/spec \ 
            --distpath /home/metka/bot/prog_test/dist \ 
            --workpath /home/metka/bot/prog_test/build \ 
            --onefile \
            test.py 

This creates the executable (filename test). I move the executable file from /home/metka/bot/prog_test/dist to /home/metka folder and try to run executable test it there. I get the following warning:
Warning: The Chromium binary specified (/home/metka/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seleniumbase/drivers) was NOT found!
(Will use default settings...)


Warning: uc_driver not found. Getting it now:

*** chromedriver to download = 129.0.6668.100 (Latest Stable)

Downloading chromedriver-linux64.zip from:
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/129.0.6668.100/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip ...
Download Complete!

Extracting ['chromedriver'] from chromedriver-linux64.zip ...
Unzip Complete!

The file [uc_driver] was saved to:
/tmp/_MEIOntOSI/seleniumbase/drivers/
uc_driver

Making [uc_driver 129.0.6668.100] executable ...
[uc_driver 129.0.6668.100] is now ready for use!

The fact is that the executable file test is searching for the uc_driver in folder /home/metka/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seleniumbase/drivers which does not exist. I have found uc_driver file only in virtual environment /home/metka/razvoj/test/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumbase/drivers/uc_driver.
What I have tried so far and found no solution:

installed seleniumbase system-wide (outside the virtual environment),
manually created folder /home/metka/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seleniumbase/drivers
used switch --add-data with pyinstaller like --add-data "/home/metka/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumbase/drivers:seleniumbase/drivers"

None of that helps.
How to solve the issue so the executable test will download the necessary dependencies (like uc_driver, etc.) only once and not on each executable run? The situation results in unnecessary network traffic with dependency downloads.
